# file put contents not working with no error

Tags: php

I am creating a cron job to remove cached files if they are older than 30 days.

```
<?php
$path = 'tmp/cache/';
$job = '';
if ($handle = opendir($path)) {

    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        $filelastmodified = filemtime($path . $file);
        if((time() - $filelastmodified) > 30*24*3600)
        {
            unlink($path . $file);
            $job .= "Deleted: $file \n";
        }

    }

    closedir($handle);
}
if(file_put_contents('logs/cache/log_'.date("j.n.Y").'.log', $job)){
    echo "Done.";
}else{
    echo "Error";
}
?>
```

However there is no errors, but the log file doesnt write. The directory exists and the file is chmodded to 777 but it wont write the file. What is causing it not to write the file? also is \n the best way for a return in a file?

var_dump produces this: `int(0)`

Comment: What does file_put_contents return ?, can you do a var_dump and show us the outputs  ?

Comment: @SofieneDJEBALI see post for var_dump.

Comment: You need to check your php ini that this function is enabled. And you can user error_reporting(E_ALL) for getting information about errors. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

Comment: Make `echo $job` what is return ??

Comment: Did you get `Done` Message??

Comment: @JensonMJohn no i didnt because my $job variable was empty it was returning 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file_put_contents does not return false beacause, it's actually working.

file_put_contents return you the the number of bytes that were written to the file.
 your variable `$job` is empty.

Comment: Ah so it doesn't return true/false for if the file was successfully created.

Comment: Nop, and your $job variable is empty because it does not enter in your (time() - $filelastmodified) condition